# Show post count in custom taxonomy page

Tags: posts, customization, pages, taxonomy, count

How can I show the post count in a taxonomy page. I tried some codes but I could not get success. I will locate this information on the top of taxonomy page.

```
foreach ( get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'taxonomy' ) as $term )
{
  echo  $term->count ;
}
```

Comment: I am using woody snippets plugin to insert php code to custom taxonomy page because i create custom taxonomies with post type builder plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

İ found a solution:

```
$posts = get_queried_object();
echo $posts->count;
```